# Como iterar dentro de uma lista que fica dentro de outra classe?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, classes, iterator

Gostaria de saber se é possível iterar uma lista que está em outra classe.
Em uma rede social, todo usuário tem uma lista de posts, mas essa lista está definida só na classe `User` como iterar dentro dela ?
Método que quero aplicar:

```
rede.addComment ("u3", "u1", "p1", new Comment ("c1", 
                 "Com pão de queijo ? tudo di bão"));
```

Classe `SocialNetwork`:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class SocialNetwork {

    private List<User> users;

    public SocialNetwork () {
        users = new ArrayList<User>();
    }

    public void addUser(User user) { 
        users.add(user);        
    }

    public User getUserById(String id) {

        for (User u : users) {
            if (id == u.getId())
                return u;
        }

        return null;

    }

    private Post getPostById(Post post, User id) {
        for (User getUserById(id) i : posts) {

        }
        return null;
    }

    public void addPost(String id, Post post) {
        User userId = getUserById(id);
        userId.addPost(post);
    }

    public void addComment(String user1, String user2, String postId, Comment comment) {
        User userComented = getUserById(user1);
        User userPosted = getUserById(user2);
        Post post = getPostById(postId);

    }}
```

Classe `User`:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class User {

    private String id;
    private String name;
    private List<User> friends;
    private List<Post> posts;

    public User(String id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        friends = new ArrayList<>();
        posts = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void addFriend (User friend) {
        friends.add(friend);
    }

    public void addPost (Post post) {
        posts.add(post);
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public List<Post> getUserPosts() {
        return this.posts;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "(" + id +"," + name +")";
    }}
```

Classe `Post`:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Post {

    private String id;
    private String content;
    private List<Comment> comments;
    private List<String> likes;

    public Post(String id, String content) {
        this.id = id;
        this.content = content;
        comments = new ArrayList<>();
        likes = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void addComment (Comment comment) {
        comments.add(comment);
    }}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Olá, Breno!

Obtenha a lista da classe `User` da seguinte forma

```
User user = new User();
List<Post> posts = user.getUserPosts();
```

Agora você pode usar a lista de `Post`s como quiser

```
for(Post p: posts) {
   // p é um objeto, use sua função aqui
}
```

Mas, se de alguma forma, você realmente quer fazer isso dentro da sua classe `User`, pode criar um método que faz esse trabalho

```
public class User {
    List<Post> posts;

    /*...*/

    public void setPosts(List<Post> posts) {
       this.posts = posts;
    }

    /*...*/

    public void postsIterator(SocialNetwork network) {
       for(Post p: this.posts) {
          network.addComment(); // seu método aqui
        }
    }
}
```

E então é só passar uma instância de sua classe `SocialNetwork` e chamar seu método para processar os posts. Espero que ajude!